# Is it possible to pass an OpenAPI spec as a JSON object to ReDoc?

Tags: openapi, redoc

I created an OpenAPI JSON document for a RESTful service and am using ReDoc to display it.

Is there a way to pass the OpenAPI spec as a JSON object directly to ReDoc without using a JSON file or URL?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ReDoc</title>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>

    <redoc spec = {{object}} ></redoc>  <----------- Is this possible?

    <script src="/doc/bundles/redoc.standalone.js"> </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by manual initalizing the redoc object, as an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>APIDocs</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/v2.1.2/bundles/redoc.standalone.js"> </script>
    <div id="redoc-container"></div>
    <script>
        Redoc.init(<your json object here>, {}, document.getElementById('redoc-container'))
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

More info can be found on [*redoc's official documentation*](https://redocly.com/docs/redoc/deployment/html/#the-redoc-object)

Answer (score -2):

Yes. You could pass json object or a URL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).